# "E:Read error - read (5: Input/output error), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened."

Tags: apt, software-center

So I keep trying to install things on my laptop and whenever I try to use sudo apt-get I get the same errors every  time,

```
SystemError: E:Read error - read (5: Input/output error), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Also whenever I try to open software Center through my desktop Icon it will just freeze leaving me to force quit. 
If I try to use the command software-center in my terminal I get the longest list in the world which is,

```
che.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py", line 629, in <lambda>
    return (lambda data: callback(*data), user_data)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 261, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 105, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 150, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
SystemError: E:Read error - read (5: Input/output error), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
2013-10-13 10:13:52,685 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py", line 629, in <lambda>
    return (lambda data: callback(*data), user_data)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 261, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 105, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 150, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
SystemError: E:Read error - read (5: Input/output error), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
2013-10-13 10:13:57,365 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py", line 629, in <lambda>
    return (lambda data: callback(*data), user_data)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 261, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 105, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 150, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
SystemError: E:Read error - read (5: Input/output error), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

That's only about one-tenth of the list which is too long to read. I need help, if anyone has an answer please respond

Comment: corrupt file or bad hard drive.  delete the file, apt-get update.  and see what happens.

Answer (score 22):

Your lists are corrupted, you should remove them and refresh your package lists:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

First removes the previous list, next remake the `partial` directory, third updates your list and recreates the package list of your repositories.

This could be easily fixed if you find out exactly which one is corrupted, but the log doesn't say. `apt-get update` might give you hints so instead of deleting *all* of them, just the one is corrupted.